# Assign labels from columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, label

I have the following problem, from a 5 column dataframe I need to assign a label to it but only if any of the columns has more than 2 non nan values, for example for the following dataframe:

```
Name   Orange  Blue  Red  Black
A       nan     nan   ok   nan
A       nan     nan  nan   nan
A       nan     ok    ok   nan
A        ok     nan   ok    ok
```

In this case A would have to be label as Red, I tried with the elimination of the columns with only nan values:

`df[df[~df.isnull().all()]]`

but i can't assign the label properly, any idea to optimize the process? the output can be a df with the column with more non nan vales like:

```
Name   Red  
A      ok   
A      nan   
A      ok   
A      ok
```

Comment: Can you add a clear expected output to your question ?

Comment: ready! sorry for the lack of details @Timeless

Comment: No worries, I posted an answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by using [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
N = 2 # <- adjust here the threshold

sl = df.set_index("Name").notna().sum().loc[lambda s: s.gt(N)]
​
out = df[["Name"]].join(df.iloc[:, sl])
```

Another variant (better one) :

```
out = df.loc[:, df.notna().sum() >= N]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Name  Red
0    A   ok
1    A  NaN
2    A   ok
3    A   ok
```